# Updating a non rectangular subset of values in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with a mix of numerical (float) and text columns.  Some of the numerical values seem to be off by a factor 10 and I want to modify them in place.  I can do with apply, but I was wondering if there is any way to only indexing instead.

Concretely, the code below shows a very small example, including how to calculate a boolean array indicating which values need to be scaled, but I am not able to construct an expression assigning back corrected value.  I tried variations of .loc and .ix for the last expression to not avail.

```
import pandas as pd

d0 = { "d" : ['1/1/2010', '1/1/2011', '1/1/2012'],
       "s" : ["a", "b","c"],
      "c0" : [10.0, 10.1, 100.2],
      "c1" : [10.0, 100.1, 100.2],
      "c2" : [100.0, 10.1, 10.2] }
NumCols = ["c0", "c1", "c2"]

df0 = pd.DataFrame(d0)
def Scale(x):
    return [ z if z < 100 else z/10 for z in x]
df0[NumCols] = df0[NumCols].apply(Scale)  # works as expected

df1 = pd.DataFrame(d0)
TooBig = df1[ NumCols ] >= 100                   # correctly identifies positions to scale
df1[NumCols][TooBig] = df1[NumCols][TooBig] / 10 # fail and issue warning
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting an error in this line,

```
df1[NumCols][TooBig] = df1[NumCols][TooBig] / 10
```

This is because,

```
df1[NumCols][TooBig] / 10
```

yields a dataframe with NaN,

```
[3 rows x 3 columns]
      c0     c1  c2
0    NaN    NaN  10
1    NaN  10.01 NaN
2  10.02  10.02 NaN
```

You probably want to replace this with,

```
df1[NumCols] = (df1[NumCols][TooBig] / 10).fillna(df1)

[3 rows x 3 columns]
      c0     c1    c2         d  s
0  10.00  10.00  10.0  1/1/2010  a
1  10.10  10.01  10.1  1/1/2011  b
2  10.02  10.02  10.2  1/1/2012  c
```

Comment: I was not aware of this use of fillna.  This opens new possibilities, even outside of the solution to this specific problem.  Thank you.

Comment: I also discovered where() that has an optional argument, so you can select based on a bit mask between two sources.  This is similar to performing the selection and the fillna in the same call.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that your code is breaking because of 2 reasons:

1. You try to use chained assignment and the error gives the link to the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) explaining how to deal with this.
2. Even if you would use `.loc` in the last statement: `df1.loc[TooBig, NumCols] /= 10` you would still have an error, because `.loc` does not accept `dataframe` as in input. Your `TooBig` is a DataFrame (see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing).)

You could do this (instead of you last line):

```
for c in NumCols:
    df1.loc[df1[c]>=100, c] /= 10.
```

And this will yield:

```
df1[NumCols]
      c0     c1    c2
0  10.00  10.00  10.0
1  10.10  10.01  10.1
2  10.02  10.02  10.2
```

And despite the loop it performs tiny bit faster then using `fillna` approach :-)

```
#timeit results for loop approach:
100 loops, best of 3: 2.63 ms per loop
```

vs.

```
#timeit results for fillna approach:
100 loops, best of 3: 3.05 ms per loop
```

Comment: This works of course, it is similar to the apply solution, it just make the loop over the columns explicit.  I am still surprised that this is a faster than a solution with no (apparent) loop.  Thanks for the performance numbers.

Comment: I may be doing something wrong, but on my machine I got the following timing information: 1.58 ms for apply on subset of columns, 62.3 ms for fillna, and 2.65 ms for the explicit loop.